# Why does making a div display:inline make it suddenly go smaller?

Tags: html, css

Pretty simple question really when I make a div inline it seems to lose its height?

Any ideas? I'm scratching my head....

UPDATE: after fiddling around I found another display type called "inline-block" which seems to allow me to keep items inline (unordered lists for example) and then set a height for them.

Is this a solution to the problem of inline elements losing the height setting?

Comment: Depending on the browser, it may give an "explanation".

Comment: As explained below, Inline elements don't have heights or widths. inline-block is a way and also THE way to make elements inline and still assign block-level properties to them, such as height and width. Further reading: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if I use an inline-block I can make elements sit inline but not lose the height.

Comment: If your using inline-block, make sure you're checking your website against IE7 as you need to do some hacks to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Inline elements don't have heights...  You've reached the very essence of difference between inline and block.

Answer (score 0):

The height of an inline element is dictated by the `line-height` of the parent element, with whose contents they're now in-line. Therefore they're unable to have an explicit `height` of their own.

Similarly for the `width`, except that's dictated by the width of the contents.